# How to apply a cloud texture to a material in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I am trying to make water in Cycles Render, and I made a cloud texture for it, but the cloud texture wasn't assigned to the water.

When I tried to apply it a texture for its color, it didn't have the cloud texture in the drop down list.

And if it involves assigning a texture in the materials tab, how do I change the color?

Answer (score 1):

The texture menu doesn't work for Cycles Render, only for Blender Internal, instead you can add a Noise texture inside the Node Editor of the water material in Cycles[image]